# How to not print empty line?

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrap some links from a site but I'm running into an issue where my for loop will stop at the first link.

**Currently What I have**

```
import requests
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



url = 'http://ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a'
f = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.content, 'lxml')
fighter_links = soup.find('td', {
    'class': 'b-statistics__table-col'
    }).find_all('a')


fighterLinks = []
for anchor in fighter_links:
    # urls = anchor['href']
    fighterLinks.append(anchor['href'])

print(fighterLinks)
```

When I print I'm getting

```
['http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/93fe7332d16c6ad9']
```

**Site I'm trying to pull from**

[image]

Comment: Check out [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you do

```
fighter_links = soup.find('td', {'class': 'b-statistics__table-col'}).find_all('a')
```

you are only getting the first table record. soup.find will only return the first match that it finds. what you need to do is change it to

```
fighter_links = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'b-statistics__table-col'})
fighterLinks = []
```

that will get you all the table enteries that match your class name, and from there you need to do loop to extract out the links

```
for link in fighter_links:
    if(link.find('a')):
        fighterLinks.append(link.find('a').get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help, but I hope it does:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a'
f = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.content, 'lxml')

aa = soup.select("a.b-link_style_black")
fighterLinks = []
for i in aa:
    for k in i:
        fighterLinks.append(aa[aa.index(i)].attrs["href"])
print(fighterLinks)
```

outputs:

```
['http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/93fe7332d16c6ad9', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/93fe7332d16c6ad9', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/15df64c02b6b0fde', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/15df64c02b6b0fde', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/15df64c02b6b0fde', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/59a9d6dac61c2540', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/59a9d6dac61c2540', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/b361180739bed4b0', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/b361180739bed4b0', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/b361180739bed4b0', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/3329d692aea4dc28', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/3329d692aea4dc28', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/3329d692aea4dc28', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/2f5cbecbbe18bac4', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/2f5cbecbbe18bac4', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/2f5cbecbbe18bac4', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/c0ed7b208197e8de', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/c0ed7b208197e8de', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/c0ed7b208197e8de', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/5140122c3eecd307', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/5140122c3eecd307', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/c9f6385af6df66d7', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/c9f6385af6df66d7', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/c9f6385af6df66d7', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/aa6e591c2a2cdecd', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/aa6e591c2a2cdecd', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/aa6e591c2a2cdecd', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/7279654c7674cd24', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/7279654c7674cd24', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/7279654c7674cd24', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/1c5879330d42255f', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/1c5879330d42255f', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/989b85f6540c86b1', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/989b85f6540c86b1', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/989b85f6540c86b1', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/2620f3eb21c79614', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/2620f3eb21c79614', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/83b00f7597e5ac83', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/83b00f7597e5ac83', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/83b00f7597e5ac83', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/a77633a989013265', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/a77633a989013265', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/a77633a989013265', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/79cb2a690b9ba5e8', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/79cb2a690b9ba5e8', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/79cb2a690b9ba5e8', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/1338e2c7480bdf9e', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/1338e2c7480bdf9e', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/1338e2c7480bdf9e', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/0e9869d712e81f8f', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/0e9869d712e81f8f', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/0e9869d712e81f8f', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/ebc5af72ad5a28cb', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/ebc5af72ad5a28cb', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/a08ddd04eaffd81d', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/a08ddd04eaffd81d', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/a08ddd04eaffd81d', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/44aa652b181bcf68', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/44aa652b181bcf68', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/501821d7fb7b95c1', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/501821d7fb7b95c1', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/6cadc0a0ba7dc015', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/6cadc0a0ba7dc015', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/6cadc0a0ba7dc015', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/8f382b3baa954d2a', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/8f382b3baa954d2a', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/8f382b3baa954d2a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Requests will fail on some connections in this instance. Better use cloudscraper: (`pip install cloudscraper`)

```
import cloudscraper
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()

soup = BeautifulSoup(scraper.get("http://ufcstats.com/statistics/fighters?char=a").text)

links = soup.select_one('.b-statistics__table').select('a')
print(set([x.get('href') for x in links]))
```

This returns:

```
{'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/a08ddd04eaffd81d', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/15df64c02b6b0fde', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/a77633a989013265', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/0e9869d712e81f8f', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/1338e2c7480bdf9e', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/3329d692aea4dc28', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/79cb2a690b9ba5e8', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/44aa652b181bcf68', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/c0ed7b208197e8de', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/b361180739bed4b0', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/59a9d6dac61c2540', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/ebc5af72ad5a28cb', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/501821d7fb7b95c1', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/989b85f6540c86b1', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/7279654c7674cd24', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/aa6e591c2a2cdecd', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/8f382b3baa954d2a', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/2f5cbecbbe18bac4', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/93fe7332d16c6ad9', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/c9f6385af6df66d7', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/2620f3eb21c79614', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/5140122c3eecd307', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/83b00f7597e5ac83', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/6cadc0a0ba7dc015', 'http://ufcstats.com/fighter-details/1c5879330d42255f'}
```